# filter pair of lenders that both lent to a borrower, but not in a same loan

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

In new loan id=1, firm S borrows from two lenders, A,B. In old loan id=2, S borrows from lenders B,E,F. In old loan id=3, S borrows from A,E,G.

Data is in the following form:

```
loan_id_new  loan_id_old  lender  lender_old
1            2            A       B
1            2            A       E
1            2            A       F
1            2            B       B
1            2            B       E
1            2            B       F
1            3            A       A
1            3            A       E 
1            3            A       G 
1            3            B       A       
1            3            B       E       
1            3            B       G
```

I want to rule out any pair of (lender, lender_old) that is in the same loan (old or new).
The result should be like:

```
loan_id_new  loan_id_old  lender  lender_old
1            2            A       F
1            3            B       G
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure someone here will give you a more efficient/Pythonic way of doing this, but in the meantime my thoughts (if I've understood correctly are) are:

```
lenders1 = {'A', 'B'}
lenders2 = {'B', 'E', 'F'}
lenders3 = {'A', 'E', 'G'}

for lender in [lenders1, lenders2, lenders3]:
   mask = (df['lender'].isin(lender)) & (df['lender_old'].isin(lender))
    df = df[~mask]
```

Untested, written on phone, sorry for bad indentation.

Comment: can you use groupby and apply to solve it? The lenders list may vary and the dataset is too large to use loop.